# Calculating Means for Multiple Variables based on top 3 condition

Tags: r

I have 23 variables out of which 22 are numeric variables which is survey data of people based on parameters like `Service`, `Reliability` etc all having values in range 1-10 and 99 = neutral.

23rd variable is gender.

I am supposed to divide the data into male and female

```
b <- data.frame(subset(Dataset, Dataset$Gender =='1')) #Male
c <- subset(Dataset, Dataset$Gender =='2') #Female
```

Then i have removed over here variable number 20 which is Age which is not required for the analysis

```
x <- data.frame(b[c(1:19,21,22,23,24)])
y <- data.frame(c[c(1:19,21,22,23,24)])
```

So dataframes `x` and `y` have 22 numeric variables and 1 categorical variable which is male and female respectively for `x` and `y`.

Now i am supposed to get mean for 22 numeric variables in such a way that for each variable selected if values are in range 0-7 & 99 then that observation should not be selected and if the values are from 8-10 then that observation should be selected and the mean should be obtained for collection of such observations(8-10)

```
z <- subset(colMeans(x[c(1:19,21,22,23)]), x[c(1:19,21,22,23)] > 7 & x[c(1:19,21,22,23)] != 99) #This is where i am facing a problem. I am not getting proper values and results as per my expectation.
```

Please if you have any ideas how to resolve it please help me out

Comment: (1) Post the output of `dput(head(Dataset, 20))`. (2) There's a logical error, if your description of the problem is right then in your `subset` it should be `|`.

Comment: dput((Service Reliability Gender
 9        2          1
 99       10       1
 2        5          1)

Comment: Hi i am new to stackoverflow so i don't know how to use dput() function could you please guide me with that.

Comment: No it should be "&"  right because we want values >7  and !=99 which is values from 8-10.

Comment: count<-0
z<- lapply(p[, c(1:19,21,22,23)]) function(x)
  for(i in 1:n) 
    if (x <7 & x=99) next()
      count= 0 + i 
      
      count /#number of observations it had. I am looking for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, maybe the following will do it.
First, let's make up some data, since you haven't yet posted a dataset example.

```
set.seed(510)
Dataset <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:10, 99), 2400, TRUE), ncol = 24))
names(Dataset)[24] <- "Gender"
Dataset$Gender <- sample(1:2, 100, TRUE)
```

Now, the code.

```
a <- subset(Dataset, Gender == 1, select = c(1:19, 21:24))  # Male
b <- subset(Dataset, Gender == 2, select = c(1:19, 21:24))  # Female

sapply(a[-ncol(a)], function(x) mean(x[x > 7 & x != 99]))
sapply(b[-ncol(b)], function(x) mean(x[x > 7 & x != 99]))
```